# center a row with one <td> element, when other row has many <td>

Tags: html, css

I want to center a `<td>` element in a row, when other row has many `<td>` elements. But the first row's `<td>` element always sits in the first column position, and it's not moving to center.

Here is my code sample:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Problem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>65</td>
    <td rowspan="3" width="100px">66</td>
    <td>67</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>77</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>85</td>
    <td>87</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>85</td>
    <td>86</td>
    <td>87</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and here is the result, I want the one  element to get in center without having other  element, and it should take same width and height of first column  elements. Images is here - [image: Result i get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want a caption instead of a cell:

> [image]

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Problem</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>65</td>
    <td rowspan="3" style="width: 100px">66</td>
    <td>67</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>77</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>85</td>
    <td>87</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>85</td>
    <td>86</td>
    <td>87</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice solution, but i shifted to div rather than using a table for this task. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you don't want the `<td>` element to span the entire row. Instead you want it to be positioned in the "center" column.

If you know the dimensions in advance, you can simply create empty `<td>`s before it and hide them.

```css
table { empty-cells: hide; }
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td></td> <!-- Empty TD for positioning -->
    <td>Problem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>65</td>
    <td rowspan="3" width="100px">66</td>
    <td>67</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>77</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>85</td>
    <td>87</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>85</td>
    <td>86</td>
    <td>87</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's a good solution, but I want to resize the Problem <td> along with 65 <td> rather than 66, is there any way to change the width of the cell? Thank you so much. @Marcelo

Comment: @aziz So you want it to be the width of the first column but be placed in the location of the second column, correct? What is the behavior you want if the first column is wider than the second? What if the first is narrower than the second?

Comment: Honestly, I would not recommend a table layout if you are wanting to present things this way. If even possible, you will be fighting the table positioning/sizing the entire time.

Comment: I also think so, and I decided to not use table layout. Thanks bro for your kind opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table border="1"> 
  <tr>
    <td style="border:5px"></td>
    <td>56</td>
    <td style="border:5px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>65</td>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>67</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>77</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>85</td>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>87</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

if you want column then you can remove that style part
and this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```html
    <table border="1">
        <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="3" align="center">Problem</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>65</td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="100px" align="center">66</td>
            <td>67</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>75</td>
            <td>77</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>85</td>
            <td>87</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>85</td>
            <td align="center">86</td>
            <td>87</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: This helps no one. Please explain your solution.

Answer (score -1):

The amount of columns in a table are defined by the maximum amount of columns in any given row of a table. Since your table uses 3 columns, the row with only a single `td` cell will not fit across.

To fix this, the `colspan` attribute is what you want.

However, since you want to keep the cell at the size of others in the same column, you'll use empty `td` elements to do this. Example below:

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>1 column</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 column</td>
    <td>1 column</td>
    <td>1 column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want colspan 1 and it will position in center and take only one cell space.

Comment: Seriously? A downvote? In your case, you would add empty `td` elements on each side of your individual cell.

Comment: I tried that, but it take the same sapce of the cell below it, is there any way to change the width of the cell respective to the cell below it.

Comment: Can you tell me, how can i change the width of the "single center column" width, Please?

Comment: @aziz You cannot edit the width of a single column in a table. It will affect the entire column.

Comment: That;s what I wanted to .. Thanks brother for your kind help. Now i should go back to div rather than table.